# Incorrect graph generated by graphviz library

Tags: c, svg, graphviz, dot

I am currently struggling with GraphViz.

Here is my code :

```
GVC_t* gvc = gvContext();

FILE* f = fopen("out.dot", "r");
Agraph_t* G = agread (f);
fclose(f);
gvLayout (gvc, G, "dot");

gvRenderFilename (gvc, G, "svg", "mygraph.svg");
gvFreeLayout(gvc, G);

agclose (G);

gvFreeContext(gvc);
```

However, the output given by this code and the output given by the call to `dot -Tsvg out.dot > output.svg` are completely different :

- The command line call to `dot` produces a good-looking graph
- This code produces a graph where all nodes are at the same place, making it unreadable.

Strangely, when I change the algorithm in `gvLayout (gvc, G, "dot");` from dot to neato or other layout algorithms, it works well (except for twopi), but the dot layout engine is the only one that produces acceptable results for my graphs.

Does anybody know what is wrong with my code?